# Проблема с нахождением элементов Namespace

Tags: c#, xml

Есть некий xml с пространством имён. Из него я пробую выбрать тэги следующим образом:

```
  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(fileName);
        // получим корневой элемент
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns3", "");

        XmlElement root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList datasved = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:PRequest/@ДатаСвед", nsmgr);
        XmlNodeList idsved = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:PRequest/@ИдСвед", nsmgr);
        XmlNodeList datazapis = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:Свед/@ДатаЗапис", nsmgr);
        XmlNodeList nomerzapis = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:Свед/@НомерЗапис", nsmgr);
        XmlNodeList kodOrgan = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:Свед/ns2:Орган/@Кодorgan", nsmgr);
        XmlNodeList naimOrgan = root.SelectNodes("//ns2:Свед/ns2:Орган/@Наимorgan", nsmgr);


        for (int i = 0; i<datazapis.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox_view.Items.Add(datasved[0].InnerXml + ";" + idsved[0].InnerXml + ";" + 
            datazapis[i].InnerXml + ";" +   nomerzapis[i].InnerXml + ";" + 
            kodOrgan[i].InnerXml + ";" + naimOrgan[i].InnerXml);

        }
```

Вопрос следующий, не везде есть ДатаЗаписи или НомерЗаписи, парсер берет следующий элемент который найдет, где ДатаЗапис определена. Как сделать чтоб парсер шёл по порядку, если такой элемент не находит, ставил пробел?

Comment: Если вам нужен полный ручной обход, то используйте XmlReader. Если хочется "покомпактнее" - то лучший выход  - десериализация.

Comment: *Как сделать чтоб парсер шёл по порядку* - у вас безпорядок, просто набор списков. Вам прийдется делать поиск в списке нужно елемента методом - перебор и сравнение по-ключевому полю. Вы не указали ключевое поле... поэтому не понятно как хотите сопоставить.

Comment: Через XmlReader, сначала перебор всех узлов и пространств имен?

Comment: Есть полезные ссылки, по ключевым полям? или по XmlReader с пространством имен

Comment: XmlReader  в гугле 1)so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp 2) microsoft http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: *сначала* - нет, сначала не получится. Есть как минимум три способа которые абсолютно разные. 1)XmlDocument  ваш,  2)XmlReader 3) XmlSerializer  Я считаю что 3 - само лучше. 2- нужно если полный хаос. 1-это просто "порт" библиотеки msxml.dll с с++ на c# (если в плюсах делфи или js/vbs с ней работали то в с# будет всё ясно)

Comment: К вашей проблеме можно прийти переписав и 2 и 3-тим способом. Нужно вначале вам продумать, как именно сопоставлять елементы в двух разных списках.

Comment: у вас проблемы с парсингом XML, который вы не показываете. Приведите пример вашего XML